# Make one VNC server appear as two displays in RHEL

Tags: rhel, gnome, vmware, vnc

I have a VNC server running in virtual mode in RHEL and I am viewing it on a PC which has two screens. I can make the server use both of my screens by setting the resolution large enough:

```
xrandr -s 3840x1200
```

The problem is now the applications on the Linux side think that there is just one huge display. When I maximize a window it fills both of my screens. What I want to happen is the window to fill the one screen that it currently occupies. This is how things behaved when I actually had two displays connected to a linux box.

How can I make the VNC server understand that there are two displays instead of one big one?  I am using RHEL 5.10 (but will soon be upgrading to 6) and the desktop is Gnome 2.16.0.  After looking into my xorg.conf file I realize that this is all being run by vmware.  I am hopeful that there is some change to this file that would give me the result I am looking for.

I do not have root access on this machine.  However, if the solution requires root access I would be happy to hear it since I could then try to get my sysadmin to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the solution will not be found using VNC;  I think VNC will only give you one window at a time.

maybe consider an X agent on your client host, and port the display back to your client via xdmcp and the DISPLAY variable?  I'm not sure you'll see success there either, but I suspect the chances are higher.  Good luck!